# How to call instance based functions and access instance variables from within Django migrations

Tags: python, django, import, migration, python-import

There are instance-based functions and instance variables that I need to call from a custom Django migrations file. Can I do this, and if so, how?

For example I have an instance, c, of class Car. How do I call c.honk() from within a migrations file, or access c.colour ?

P.S.
I know that I can 'import' models within the migrations file using ModelName = apps.get_model('appname', 'ModelName') , and I know that I can call class-based functions by doing **import**('appname').pythonfile.functionname .  In other words I know how to do things like call Car.get_components() from within a migrations file.

P.P.S. I'm not sure whether "instance-based functions" and "class-based functions" is the right terminology, but I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#historical-models) you can't access arbitrary code (custom methods, `__init__`, `save` etc.) in migrations, however you can use custom managers if they have `use_in_migrations = True` attribute.